# Why does LiquidHaskell fail to take guard into account?

Tags: liquid-haskell

I am following the Liquid Haskell tutorial:

```
http://ucsd-progsys.github.io/liquidhaskell-tutorial/04-poly.html
```

and this example fails:

```
module Test2 where

import Data.Vector
import Prelude hiding (length)

vectorSum :: Vector Int -> Int
vectorSum vec = go 0 0
  where
    go acc i
      | i < length vec  = go (acc + (vec ! i)) (i + 1)
      | otherwise       = acc
```

with the following error:

```
Error: Liquid Type Mismatch

 10 |       | i < length vec  = go (acc + (vec ! i)) (i + 1)
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   Inferred type
     VV : {v : GHC.Types.Int | v == acc + ?b}

   not a subtype of Required type
     VV : {VV : GHC.Types.Int | VV < acc
                                && VV >= 0}

   In Context
     ?b : GHC.Types.Int
     acc : GHC.Types.Int
```

The question is why? The guard (i < length vec) should ensure that (vec ! i) is safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a termination error. Liquid Haskell here seems to assume that `acc` is the termination metric of `go` (probably because it's the first `Int` argument). As such it should always be non-negative and decreasing in each iteration (hence the error message you get).

The way to fix this is providing a correct termination metric, which fulfills the above criteria. Here this would be `length vec - i` and the corresponding signature for `go` is:

```
{-@ go :: _ -> i:_ -> _ /[length vec - i] @-}
```

or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't know which version of LH you were using but I just had the exact same problem. The tutorial states that

> LiquidHaskell verifies vectorSum – or, to be precise, the safety of
>   the vector accesses vec ! i. The verification works out because
>   LiquidHaskell is able to automatically infer
>
> ```
> go :: Int -> {v:Int | 0 <= v && v <= sz} -> Int
> ```
>
> which states that the second parameter i is between 0 and the length
>   of vec (inclusive). LiquidHaskell uses this and the test that i < sz
>   to establish that i is between 0 and (vlen vec) to prove safety.

They also state that the tutorial is not in accordance with the current version of LiquidHaskell.

It seems that the (refinement-)type inference of LH has changed a bit since the tutorial was written, probably generalizing types more than before, which results in this problem.

The problem is NOT that LH doesn't figure out the guard properly. The problem is that it fails to verify the property `0 <= v`.

The following checks fine with version 0.8.6.2 of LH:

```
{-@ LIQUID "--short-names"         @-}
{-@ LIQUID "--no-termination"      @-}
{-@ LIQUID "--reflection"          @-}

import Prelude hiding (length)
import Data.Vector 

{-@ go' :: v:Vector Int -> Int -> {i:Int | i>=0 } ->Int @-}
go' :: Vector Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
go' vec acc i
    | i < sz    = go' vec (acc + (vec ! i)) (i + 1)
    | otherwise = acc
    where sz = length vec

vecSum :: Vector Int -> Int
vecSum vec = go' vec 0 0
```

It seems that LH infers thas go is a function in its own right and might be called with an integer smaller than 0 (which it obviously isn't).

I am still playing with that example to convince LH of this fact. If anybody had more success on this please leave a comment.

---

**EDIT:**

I found the following paragraph in the same tutorial; It seems that this might have changed:

> At the call `loop 0 n 0 body` the parameters `lo` and `hi` are instantiated
>   with `0` and `n` respectively, which, by the way is where the inference
>   engine deduces non-negativity.